# Rails 3 - how to refresh updated code

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, view, ftp

I have my RoR app on FTP and if I open some file through FTP and for example I will add to my **view** one line of text, then save this file back on FTP and refresh my page, so I don't see  that one new line of text that I added.

I have to push COMMAND+R a few seconds a then sometimes I see in browser the new line of text...

It's terrible work, how can I update the file of my RoR project through FTP? (I can't use capistrano).

Thank tou.

Comment: ok, so if you want to make some changes through FTP, you must run following command: **touch /../tmp/restart.txt**

Comment: Maybe try SSHing into the box. Also, make sure your environment on that box is development.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can open `tmp/restart.txt` on your FTP server via any text editor and press Ctrl+S (save it), so file will be `touched` and server will be restarted