# how to tell my rails app to use new version of code in lib folder?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, windows-7

I'm wondering if this is specific to Win7. I have an app. I hit an exception while running it. I then change the line of code that was broken and send the Post again (by interacting with the page, since it's a PRG, not hitting F5). However, I still get the same exception. I've tested this by changing some logging messages and get the same result: the new code is not seen.

The code I'm altering is in my lib folder. That definitely seems to be the issue. But I have this in my application.rb: `config.autoload_paths << 'lib'` and `config.autoload_paths += Dir["#{config.root}/lib/**/"]` -- that looks like it covers it (possibly twice).

I've tried the solutions in these posts:

[Rails3 not reloading code in lib while in development mode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4018757/rails3-not-reloading-code-in-lib-while-in-development-mode)

[Rails 3 - how to refresh updated code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7941812/rails-3-how-to-refresh-updated-code)

Neither one worked. The only differences that I can see is that I'm running a debugger and I'm on Win7. If I restart Mongrel the new code is used.

What can I do to get the Rails runtime to use the new code without restarting?

For reference, this is what I see when I start the debugger:

```
Fast Debugger (ruby-debug-ide 0.4.17.beta8, ruby-debug-base 0.11.30.pre3) listens on 127.0.0.1:19223
=> Booting Mongrel
=> Rails 3.1.1 application starting in development on http://127.0.0.1:3001
=> Call with -d to detach
=> Ctrl-C to shutdown server
```

Comment: What is in your `config/environments/development.rb` file? Could you show us that please?

Comment: Sure, but that's 20+ lines, could you be more specific?

Comment: Perhaps this? `config.action_controller.perform_caching = false`

Comment: If you change your configuration, you have to restart your server. If you dont mean you configuration, please add more details

Comment: @Lichtamberg: "The code I'm altering is in my lib folder" from OP.

Comment: Can you confirm you have restarted your server ?

Comment: @DavidSulc Here's what I do to test this: load a page, see log file, change logging string somewhere, load page again, string in log is not changed. Stop server. Start server. Run app, load page. Changed string in log message is now present in log. Also I did mention that I was restarting the server in the OP. But I want to be able to see the changed code without restarting server -- time consuming, plus I thought Rails could do this.

Comment: @jcollum 20 lines is fine. I'm interested in the `config.cache_classes` line.

Answer (score 3):

TO the best of my knowledge, code in `/lib` is by default loaded once and only once, when the server starts. Therefore, if you change code in your `/lib` folder, you'll need to restart the server to see the changes.

If you want to have code loaded on each request, use `require_dependency` http://apidock.com/rails/v3.1.0/ActiveSupport/Dependencies/Loadable/require_dependency

Naturally, you'll only want to use `require_dependency` in development mode, and a normal `require` in test and production modes.

Comment: That seems to have done the trick. I recall reading that but I read "require_dependency" as "require" and thought "hey I already have that!"